# alternative for opening mdl files?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, uml

I have received some mdl files that were created using an old version of Rational Rose. I have tried to open them with StarUML, but this tool does not bring support to that type of files.
I would like to know if there is another alternative for opening this type of files? If they were open source it would be great. My operating system is Windows 7.
Thanks